# text gets scrambled when inserted through .html() jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, scramble

In a web page I'm doing there's a table where by clicking on each row you can modify it. This is done by substituting the content of each cell with an input field containing the relative value. In order to let the user cancel the changes made I save the contents of the whole table row before making the substitution, which I then use to compose the new html string to put in the table row (basically, I just put it in a function call which is then called when a button is pressed to revert the changes). if I try to display it through alerts the string looks fine. However, firebug returns an error because apparently the string gets scrambled after I put it in the page by calling .html on the . 
What I mean is that instead of being

```
<tr><td>somedata</td><td><input type=button onclick=fun('oldTrContent')/></td></tr>
```

it's

```
<tr><td>somedata</td><td><input type=button oldTrContentNotInOrder') onclick=fun(/></td></tr>
```

which clearly can't work. I tried putting some alerts in the function in order to see if this behavior was caused by some formatting error, but everything looks fine up to the moment of the call to .html().
The code I used is this:

```
function mostraModificaCompet(ids, nome){
var id='#'+nome;
var statoPrec=escape($(id).html());
alert(statoPrec);
var d=$(id+" .data").html();
var c=$(id+" .caus span").html();
var de=$(id+" .descr").html();
var pu=$(id+" .prezzou").html();
var q=$(id+" .qta").html();
var pt=$(id+" .prezzot").html();
var iu=$(id+" .ivau").html();
var it=$(id+" .ivat").html();
var t=$(id+" .tot").html();
var r=$(id+" .res").html();
var pr=$(id+" .progr").html();
var str="<td class=data ><input type=text value="+d+" /></td><td class=caus ><select class=selcaus ></select></td><td class=descr ><input type=text value="+de+" />\
</td><td class=prezzou ><input type=text value="+pu+" /></td><td class=qta ><input type=text value="+q+" /></td><td class=prezzot ><input type=text value="+pt+" disabled /></td>\
<td class=ivau ><input type=text value="+iu+" /></td><td class=ivat ><input type=text value="+it+" disabled /></td><td class=tot ><input type=text value="+t+" disabled /></td><td>\
<input type=button value='Conferma' onclick=modificaCompet("+ids+", '"+nome+"') /></td><td><input type=button value=Annulla onclick=ripristinaCompet('"+nome+"', '"+statoPrec+"') /></td>";
alert(str);
$(id).html(str);
}
```

the variable where I save the old content is statoPrec, which I then use when composing str (it's at the end of the string). 
Thanks in advance to anyone who answers.

Comment: Can you add some sample HTML and create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? It's a little hard to understand what structure you have just by looking at the code you posted.

Comment: I believe that when you are retrieving the html contents using .html() it returns the html which in turn contains double quotes. This interferes with your own usage of double quotes. Escape the quotes or use single & double quotes to differentiate

Comment: I would approach this a bit differently. How about just saving (and restoring) only the input values instead of the entire row HTML?

Comment: the jsfiddle is this: http://jsfiddle.net/kyLZf/

Comment: @Raghav: I thought that escaping the string would be enough. Do you think I should do otherwise?

Comment: @rontornambe: Yeah, in this case probably it would be even better to just use the input values instead of the string. Still, I'd like to know if there's the possibility to do it using the whole string, just in case I actually have to restore an html string in some other situation.

Comment: This code is horribly structured by the way you should use var once and add commans you could also probably combine variables and then add using .html() once instead of over and over again which causes the dom to be reconstructed each iteration.

Comment: @josh, "by the way you should use var once", I disagree, it's personal preference, but I find more advantages to multiple var statements, versus a single comma seperated var.  EDIT: Apparently others agree http://benalman.com/news/2012/05/multiple-var-statements-javascript/

Comment: @josh yes, I know it's not the prettiest code ever, but since it's for personal use I didn't really strain myself on its structure. regarding .html()'s usage, I thought the DOM got reconstructed only when I added something (which in this case happens only once per call of mostraModificaCompet). Are you saying it happens even when I read from the DOM (such as when I read all the values from the table row to put them in the input fields)? in that case, how can I avoid using it? I mean, even if I extract the whole table row I'd have to parse it some way to get to the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the value to invalid html, `onclick=modificaCompet("+ids+", '"+nome+"')` needs some quotes around it so it's `onclick=\"onclick=modificaCompet("+ids+", '"+nome+"')\"`.  And any other attributes you failed to quote.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that when initially going from the values within the td cells, those are accessible via the innerHTML.  However, once they turn into inputs, they are the value of the input, not the input's innerHTML.  You may have to make two functions where one uses the .html() of the element and the other looks for the .val() of the element.